# Bootstrapping necessary in IPTW?

Tags: survival, bootstrap, propensity-scores, treatment-effect

IPTW as in inverse probability of treatment weighting. Currently I am working on a project investigating the ATT of certain antiviral, and I found out there are several stats papers on the necessity and ways of bootstrapping when using IPTW, eg [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5157758/) and [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.00171). Yet I also found various papers in good medical journals (like JAMA) that use IPTW but do not involve bootstrapping. Propensity calculation is logistic regression and outcome modelling is weighted univariate coxph cox regression.

Do I really need to bootstrap? If so, what is the proper way to do so, ie bootstrap the data and carry out IPTW on samples, or run IPTW just once and bootstrap on the weighted data?

Comment: Are you willing to assume that the propensity score is parametric and correctly specified? If so, then the asymptotic variance of the IPTW estimator can be readily calculated - although note it relies on the outcome regression, which must also be consistently estimated to consistently estimate the asymptotic variance.

Comment: Currently we are using logistic regression for propensity score calculation, so we are assuming that to be parametric. The latter part I don't fully understand, we are modelling outcome with weighted univariate coxph or cox regression. In one of the papers I referenced the author argued that naive variance and robust s.e. from the model itself are biased.

Comment: I would use bootstrapping; is is simple to explain and it cuts down/stops discussions about the appropriateness of how the relevant covariance structure has been calculated. The extra time to code it is worth the less time to explain why/how the error variance is estimated. And you always bootstrap the whole procedure. And note that we bootstrap the unit of analysis (so here, bootstrap "patient"s, rather than simply "rows").

Comment: I agree with @usεr11852. See my answer[here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/159489/inverse-probability-weighting-ipw-standard-errors-after-weighting-observation/532370#532370), which also addresses Ben's point. Bootstrapping is one way, and typically the most valid way, to estimate standard errors after IPW, but not the only way (and maybe not the most common way).