# When using IPW methods for causal inference, why does the robust variance lead to conservative standard errors?

Tags: causality, weights

I'm trying to understand a claim that I've seen stated in a few different papers that when using IPW methods as the estimator for a causal estimand, the robust standard errors from the outcome model will be conservative. [See the appendix of Cole et al. 2007 for an example of this claim](https://academic.oup.com/aje/article/166/2/219/98478).

[See option 2 in this answer for an example of this claim on stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/532370/72298). When I've tried to run down the source for this claim, the reference that is cited is:

[Robins, JM. Marginal Structural Models. in: 1997 Proceedings of the Section on Bayesian Statistical Science. American Statistical Association, 1998: 1-10.](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/343/2013/03/msm-web.pdf)

From this paper, I can glean the theoretical development of marginal structural models estimated using inverse probability weighting, but it is not clear to me what result justifies the claim that the robust standard errors are conservative.

Is there an alternative reference that supports this claim? If not, could some kind soul point out what section of that reference justifies this claim?

Comment: This is explained on p2945 of Lunceford & Davidian (2004) (cited in your second link).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I must confess I feel like I'm still missing a piece of the argument here. Is the key bit the statement below equation 13 that "It may be shown that \Sigma^{*}_{IPW2} >= \Sigma^{*}_{IPW3}"?

Comment: Nope, it's that $\Sigma_{IPW2} = \Sigma^*_{IPW2} - H^T_{\beta,2}E^{-1}_{\beta\beta}H_{\beta,2}$, which implies the true variance $\Sigma_{IPW2}$ is the robust variance $\Sigma^*_{IPW2}$, which treats the weights as known, minus a positive definite matrix, and therefore is smaller than the robust variance.

Comment: Ah! OK, that makes sense. So the key piece is that since $\Sigma^{*}_{IPW2}$ is the variance coming from treating the IPW estimator as an M-estimator, that is what is happening under the hood when the robust standard errors are requested. That combined with the expression you stated above shows that robust variance has to be larger than the true variance.

Comment: They're both M-estimators, but one includes the estimation of the weights in the estimation (the true variance) and the other estimates the weights outside the M-estimation and estimates the weighted difference in means using M-estimation (the robust variance). $\Sigma_{IPW2}$ is the true variance and $\Sigma_{IPW2}^*$ is the robust variance.

Comment: Gotcha, Ok, you've tied that all together now. Thank you!